# Image used as source in ImageView: What sizes should I create?

Tags: android, imageview

Its very clear for me what sizes should I use for the different versions of `ic_launcher.png` inside `drawable-hdpi`, `drawable-ldpi`, `drawable-mdpi`, etc.

What I don't understand is what sizes should I use for a picture (a png) that is simply used in one Activity as an ImageView.

- I have this image in high resolution
- In a normal pocket device this image should be like 90% width
- In a tablet or larger devices, maybe 90% is too big

[image]

So, the question is:

Should I create several versions of this `an_image-file.png` for each folder in drawable?  or just use a single version of it and adjust its width via XML? I'm asking because I'm worried about using the best practice in this subject.

Comment: I believe an ImageView will scale you image, have you tried?

Answer (score 0):

There is no clear answer. Only way you can solve this is by trial and error. Sizes are defined for icons only for other image views you will have to try it on 5" smartphone 7" nexus 2 tab and 10" tablet.
At least for these three resolution you will have to create images, for other devices XML layouts will automatically adjust.